# VC++ converted old project to VS 2017 - Does not recognize system header files

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I loaded an old C++ project (ca. 2006) into Visual Studio 2017. It asked if I wanted to do a one-time conversion. Having no alternative, I OK'd.

First it complained that /ZI and /Gy- were incompatible. I googled around and figured out kind of what that was about, and got that error to hush. Now when I try to build the project, it does not find system header files, e.g. errno.h, float.h, assert.h etc..

How do I fix it?

EDIT - Here's another clue for you all. It finds latter day include files like <numeric> without .h's.

Comment: The first thing would be to check the Properties of the project to see what is old stuff that was kept during the conversion that needs to be thrown away. One thing that I have ended up doing is to make a copy of all of the source files into a folder, create a new project in that copy folder, and then start adding the source files into the project. Visual Studio, like most IDEs, has gotten so arcane and so much under the hood going on that you may never be able to fix a migrated project.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. :-)

Comment: I have source code that started with Visual Studio 6.0 and has been through a series of migrations, first to Visual Studio 2005 then Visual Studio 2013 and I am currently working with Visual Studio 2015. The jump from VS 6.0 to VS 2005 was pretty big. Afterwards it got easier. Not only is it settings of various kinds but also language specification changes can cause compiler errors and warnings. Depending on the size of the source code body, doing the new project and adding stuff can go pretty quick.

Comment: One thing with VS 2017 is that it has a lot of stuff under the hood. It can target multiple different processors (x86, ARM), multiple different template types (MFC, UWP, Win32, Android, iOS, Linux), multiple different SDKs, and on and on. Just the managed C++ versus native C++ can be a large jump. I am working with it for UWP and managed C++ to target Windows 10 IoT as a side line. Unfortunately it is a lot easier to find C# examples than it is C++.

Comment: There are some helpful clues in this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777424/visual-studio-2017-errors-on-standard-headers)