# Sleep() is undefined but it knows _sleep() exists and says to use Sleep() instead? c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I need to use some form of Sleep() to let the user stay with the speed of the program and watch things move around the screen. I have a problem with using any command that makes the program stop for a small amount of time but at least right now Sleep() seems like my best bet. I have included stdlib.h and accepts _sleep() and when I run the program it says to use Sleep() because its  been superceded by a new library. and within stdlib.h Sleep() does exist too. I'm at a complete roadblock any advice is much appreciated! (Different from the 2017 errors because I'm using 2019)

code:

```
void startGame() {
    //bool flag = true;
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        screenUpdate();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            rowsShown[i]++;
        }
        Sleep(500); // this comes out with an error
        //to show what the other one does
        _sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Sleep" is undefined 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996    '_sleep': This function or variable has been superceded by newer library or operating system functionality. Consider using Sleep instead. See online help for details.
```

[image: Image of the errors]

[image: Image of the code]

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, note pictures.  Not everyone can see pictures.

Comment: how to sleep: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184468/sleep-for-milliseconds (note that the accepted answer is outdated, there is another one for c++11)

Comment: I would use this instead: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) the reason is it makes your code more portable.

Comment: For the future: error information copy from "output" window. In VS quite often there is usuful information not shown in error window.

Comment: Well, a good place to start is are you sure you are including the correct header for [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep)?

Comment: @drescherjm this seems to work! thanks ill use this instead.

Comment: @Chipster yeah i have `#include <stdlib.h>` there at the top

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) says you need [`synchapi.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 errors on standard headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777424/visual-studio-2017-errors-on-standard-headers)

Comment: @Chipster ah thanks that's it thanks! Want to post it as the answer?

Comment: It's _not_ the answer. The documentation says the function is declared in synchapi.h, but that you should include Windows.h. And this is why we don't post answers in comments.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica So you're saying the OP needs to include `Windows.h`? If so, wouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @Chipster Yes, it would - unfortunately you forced me to provide my feedback on your answer in the same place you posted it!

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested to include `windows.h` (`#include <windows.h>`) instead of just include `synchapi.h` because

> There are a number of child header files that are automatically
>   included with windows.h. Many of these files cannot simply be included
>   by themselves (they are not self-contained), because of dependencies.

So if you just include `synchapi.h` you may get more `E0020` errors that other `identifiers are undefined`.

You can refer to "[Using Thread Local Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/using-thread-local-storage)" sample for how to use Sleep function.

If you want **Faster Builds with Smaller Header Files** you can reduce the size of the Windows header files by excluding some of the less common API declarations. More detailed information you can find at "[Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers)".

Comment: It is better to just use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{500})`.  It is more portable and there is no need to include `windows.h`