# Visual Studio C++ project on another PC fails to build

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

Tested with the following setup:

- Home - VS2017 or VS2019
- Classroom - VS2013 or VS2015.

I do code at home, then copy to my flash drive, bring it to the classroom and open a project from their PCs. Upon compilation I receive a big list of errors accessing standard header files, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777424/visual-studio-2017-errors-on-standard-headers). Happens to me with every project I create at home, and the other way around: from the classroom to home PC.

This is something that doesn't happen with C# projects, which only ask me to change the .net framework version before opening, everything works fine here.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @ThomasWoelfer Do you?

Answer (score 3):

If you created a project in VS2013 and try to open it in VS2017 or VS2019 you might need additional changes.

Check this out- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019

If you created a project in the latest version say VS2019, it is very difficult to open it in older versions such as VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it set the Omnipath to latest in vscode settings

Comment: Well clearly there's no mentions of VSCode in the OP

Comment: if you search in extensions you will find it as C# install it