# Cannot build console application with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I just installed the community version of VS 2019. I selected to build a console application that it created for me ("hello world" program). The file created is called ConsoleApplication1.cpp. I went to the build menu, selected build, and get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(441,5): warning MSB8003: The WindowsSDKDir property is not defined. Some build tools may not be found.

1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I tried to follow directions listed elsewhere on stackexchange. When I select "Project -> Properties" the Windows SDK field is blank. A value I typed in from the other StackExchange message creates an error that that version of the SDK cannot be found. So I deleted the version of the SDK and made it blank again. I also tried using "10.0" Here is where I received the advice:

[Visual Studio 2017 errors on standard headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777424/visual-studio-2017-errors-on-standard-headers)

Perhaps I did not install all the needed components. I recently checked off: "Windows Universal CRT SDK" (as per the instructions), but the build still fails. The warning is interesting. I looked that up also but have not found a solution that works. My "Platform Toolset" is Visual Studio 2019 (v142).

What might still be missing to build a console application? Thank you. I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: looks like your install is broken, I'd uninstall and try again, shouldn't need to fiddle with the SDK settings

Comment: Yes, that was my thought too. Maybe you did not add the C++ support when installing VS 2019. You can just call the installer again and install any additional parts, without having to do a full installation again.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out, none of the Windows SDKs were installed. I installed the latest one and the build now succeeds. I did not reject installing the SDKs, but I guess that's not a default. Now builds and runs.